# How to create a background image on title page with LaTeX?

Tags: titles, backgrounds

I want to put a background image on a title page of a document. Is it possible and does it work?

EDIT:
The answer by Presidenten using the [`eso-pic` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/) and my answer found after some research using the [`wallpaper` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/) both work.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Assuming you have a background file named background.png - Add this code before `\begin{document}`

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.png}%
\vfill
}}}
```

...and this immediately after `\begin{document}`:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
```

The `*` will make sure that the background picture will only be put on one page.

If you wish to use the picture on multiple pages, skip the `*`:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}
```

Then use this command to stop using the background picture:

```
\ClearShipoutPicture
```

Comment: Your solution with eso-pic is working. I found myself a solution in the meantime (look my answer), that is working too. So some choice for other reader. And upvote for your answer. :-)

Comment: Of course if you get `! Undefined control sequence... \includegraphics`, you're missing a graphics package such as `\usepackage{graphics}`

Comment: Is it possible to pass the filename for the picture as a parameter, as in `\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic{fig1.png}}` instead? What modifications have to be done to the code?

Answer (score 74):

After some research, I found an answer myself. This is a little bit different to the answer by Presidenten, both solutions work.

The [package `wallpaper`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/) works well for this purpose.

You need to import the package in the header:

```
\usepackage{wallpaper}
```

After that you can use commands like:

```
\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{0.5}{somerights.png}
\LRCornerWallPaper{0.5}{somerights.png}
```

The `LRCorner`-command places the image in the lower-right corner of the site. There are commands like `\ULCornerWallPaper` and so on for the other corners and `\CenterWallPaper` and `\TileWallPaper` for centering or tiling the image.

The `This` at the start of the command places the image only on the current page, without this the image is placed on all following pages.

The numerical argument `{0.5}` scales the image to 0.5 the size of the page.

Comment: what's the option to place the image at the "utter-center" ? Thanks by advance !

Comment: \CenterWallPaper{scale}{filename}

Comment: Didn't work for me. Nor does it show any error but just no image.

Comment: @Abi more details would be useful if you want help.

Comment: @Abi Indeed. Without any text or paragraph, it says `No pages of output.` Just add some text before or after `\ThisLRCornerWallPaper{0.5}{somerights.png}`, and it will work just fine.

Comment: note that `wallpaper` itself uses `eso-pic`. I've got option clashes when using `eso-pic`, so it might be relevant for others, too.

Answer (score 10):

The [@david-carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) response is perfect. But for my particular case I had to add the transparent parameter, as indicated below.

```
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
{\transparent{0.4} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.png}}%
\vfill
}}}
```