# Latex templates more suited to modern Tech (Web 2.0)

Tags: packages, themes, posters

I would like to know the viability of using Latex for producing posters to promote an event. Something around the lines of [this](http://www.cesium.di.uminho.pt/system/images/57/original/cartaz_semana_mobilidade.jpg?1338507122). And obviously, if there are any useful packages for this, or maybe some other tool other than latex.

PS: i know what Photoshop is of course. I just want to know what if there are any more code-oriented alternatives for this.

EDIT:
After re-reading the question i guess it's not quite clear what i want. I know how to apply images (in response to the first comment), and any overall feature i need i guess i can easily search around.
This is not a question about **"how do i do this"**, but more so **"is it a good idea?"**
Let's say i'm not a Photoshop/design kind of guy, but i'm more into coding, and i can actually do some pretty stuff (HTML+CSS for example). Is it viable for me to use Latex to produce a poster like the example above?

If yes: any package/env/template i should know about?
If no: why? and what alternatives do i have?

Comment: Not sure what part of 'this' is the key here.  If you mean putting an image on the page, you should look at things like `graphicx`, and/or the comprehensive drawing packages like `pstricks`, `tikz/pgf`, `asymptote`.  The various watermark packages would also be of use.

Comment: After reading your comment, and re-reading the question, i've edited it to make it more clear

Comment: I like using LaTeX to do things, so I won't give an unbiased answer here: it is a fine idea.  For ideas about how to include a background image, consider the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46280/8528).  The rest of the stuff in your example just look like it's a matter of putting words on a page, and *TeX is pretty good at doing that.