# How to make a background picture transparent?

Tags: backgrounds, transparency

I used the `wallpaper` package to add a background picture to a document site. My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\begin{document}
  \ThisTileWallPaper{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{hands}
  \Huge Text!
\end{document}
```

I wish to make it transparent so the result looks like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276280). I mean the `transparent` package with the command `{\transparent{0.4}}`. How can I do it? Here's the picture:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can also use TikZ.  Be sure to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \node[opacity=0.6,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)
   {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \Huge Text!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @John Kormylo. Thank you for your nice answer!

Answer (score 6):

Use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to insert the picture in the `B`ack`G`round of the page you're working on. This way you have full control over the way the image is processed, including setting the appropriate transparency level:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx,transparent}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{hands}%
  }%
}

\Huge Text!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Werner. Thank you for your answer! I receive your result only if I add braces `{}` before and behind this line `\transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{hands}`.