# Background image full with geometry magnification

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to create a titlepage with a background image (full bleed). It works when using either `eso-pic` or `wallpaper` packages as mentioned in [How to create a background image on title page with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46280/how-to-create-a-background-image-on-title-page-with-latex/46281)

But I am having a lot of trouble (spent many hours) getting the image full height and width when `trudimen` and `mag` options are given to the `geometry` package. I tried `\newgeometry` as well as just `\geometry`. The image always leaves some margin either on the right or the bottom. And, unfortunately, you can't specify `\mag` twice.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, mag=1500, truedimen,a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace{5in}
\ThisCenterWallPaper{2}{example-image-a}
\vfill
{\huge Title}
\vfill
{\large Author}
\vspace{0.2in}
{\small \today}
\vfill
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Best 1}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

The code produces this:

[image: notice the white space]

Comment: Why would you need the `mag` (magnification, 1000 = normal) option anyway?

Comment: I updated my question with another screenshot. Please answer my question in the last comment, sometimes there are easier solutions at hand - when others know the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

- I do not fully understand your problem.
- **Why do you need the `mag` (magnification) option anyway?**
- Below, I just copy and pasted the example from the manual and it seems to work.
- I used `*true*in` (the `*` is just to make it clearer) instead of `in` as mentioned in the manual.
- I also put the `mag` option first, as in the manual.

Is there still a problem?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[mag=1500, left=1truein, right=1truein, truedimen,a4paper,showframe=true]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace{5in}
\ThisCenterWallPaper{2}{example-image-a}
\vfill
{\huge Title}
\vfill
{\large Author}
\vspace{0.2in}
{\small \today}
\vfill
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Best 1}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will notice that your code, like mine, doesn't stretch the image fully and produces white space. I added an image to my question.

Comment: @karlos **(1)** I added a new screenshot, as you can see, there is no white space. If my exact code gives on your system different results, then, please say so. **(2)** Please answer the question, why you need the `mag` option anyway.