# Transparent background on cover with tilt angle

Tags: graphics

I want to put a background image on my cover where I can manually change the transparency but also change the angle of the picture.

Is it also possible to create a matrix with the same logo so that I can use the same logo multiple times as a background?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you post a more concrete question, you will get a more concrete answer. Add a minimal working example that shows what you are trying.

Comment: Thanks. Was not even sure if it works: The code I want to use looks similar to this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46280/how-to-create-a-background-image-on-title-page-with-latex - with the difference that I want to have it arranged in a matrix and also tilted.

Comment: As I said, please post a minimal example. No one knows which picture you want to put in the wall paper but this knowledge will be important for a concrete answer.